# qDebug() not displaying anything

Tags: qt, debugging, qdebug

I'm having troubles with qDebug(). I'm used to use it helping me to debug my code. But it's not displaying anything anymore. I don't know why. When I want to display a simple variable such as n in the code above, it just freezes my app a few seconds and nothing happens. The code is working when I'm using the debugger but it's not when I'm running it directly.

```
nbFlotteur1=2 
tabParam[nbflotteur1*2]

double n=0;
for(int i = 0; i<nbFlotteur1;i++)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        n = tabParam[i*2+1]-tabParam[i*2+0];
    }
    else
    {
        n = n * (tabParam[i*2+1]-tabParam[i*2+0]);
    }

}
qDebug()<<n;
```

It's working perfectly if I'm writing n into a text file.

Comment: How are you running the program? Had a similar problem, I think I solved it by restarting qtcreator.

Comment: I've restarted qtcreator and it's working now -________-'  THX